# query optimization to resolve performance issue

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have the following view which I use In my application.There is a performance issue i.e, delay in loading.so can you help in optimizing below code.Here value we get for PK_Name='Cust',CUST='000062 ' are the fields derived from table where their are stored as 
PK=' Cust : 000062'

```````
CREATE view [Audit_Customers] as 
SELECT [Type]
      ,[TableName]
      ,trim(substring (PK,1,PATINDEX('% : %',PK)-1)) [PK_Name] 
      ,trim(substring ([PK],PATINDEX('% : %',[PK])+3,len([PK])-PATINDEX('% : %',[PK]))) [CUST]
      ,[FieldName]
      ,[OldValue]
      ,[NewValue]
      ,[Created_on]``
      ,[UserName]
  FROM TABLENAME where trim(substring (PK,1,PATINDEX('% : %',PK)-1))='Cust'
GO
``````
```````

Comment: The general solution here would be to _index_ the `TABLENAME` table.  But, that would probably prove futile, because your `WHERE` clause is calling several functions, which would mean that SQL Server could not use any index.  So, you might want to consider storing the `PK_NAME` column directly.

Comment: I didn't get this    -'So, you might want to consider storing the PK_NAME column directly'

Comment: What I mean is: Add a computed column which stored the value `Cust` directly, and then create an index using that column.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

In given predicate actually you are not using key column on which it is created. 
Thanks.